# why i do not see all folders in project when i imported in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

see the code in the link below

https://github.com/dialdroid-android/DIALDroid

I have imported the project into Eclipse by this way :

File-->New--->project--->Java Project From Existing Ant BuildFile

But after importing into eclipse, I can see only src folder and build.xml and referenced libraries folder. I could not see other folders inside eclipse (such as build folder).

What I need to do to see all the folders?

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: This is on purpose, because only the build process is supposed to write into the `build` folder, but not the developer.